# Get last child in array

Tags: c#, arrays, umbraco, children

I've recently started working with Umbraco and I'm trying to get the last child from an array. This is what I have done so far:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{var page = Umbraco.Content(1127).Children[Children.Length - 1]}

<h5><a href='@page.Url'>@page.NewsTitle</a></h5>
<p>@page.NewsIntro</p>
<p class='read-more'><a href='@page.Url'>Read more...</a></p>
```

Edit:

Solution is as follows:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{
    var length = Umbraco.Content(1127).Children.Count();
    var page = Umbraco.Content(1127).Children[length - 1];
}

<h5><a href='@page.Url'>@page.NewsTitle</a></h5>
<p>@page.NewsIntro</p>
<p class='read-more'><a href='@page.Url'>Read more...</a></p>
```

Comment: I never worked with umbraco but `Children.length - 1` sounds reasonable. Why doesn't it work. What does `page` contain ?

Comment: Surely that's `.Length` not `.length`, it's C# afterall?

Comment: this was my thinking @Wndrr . The page contains a list of news articles which i wish to show the latest one in the site footer

Comment: and thanks @Lloyd I didn't spot that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `@{var page = Umbraco.Content(1127).Children[Children.Length - 1]}`

Do note the upper cased `L` in `Length`. c# is *case sensitive*, there is no array property named `length`.

Comment: nice spot. Ive corrected this but it doesnt fix the issue unfortunately

Comment: the only error im getting (where the macro is trying to be rendered) is: Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/footerNews.cshtml)

Comment: @MarkHughes88 wild guess here, but what is `Content`? Is it a method call or are you indexing a collection? You sure those aren't supposed to be `[` `]`?

Comment: content returns a dynamic object. I can get this to work if I simply change it to .Children[0] and specify the array index. But this is no-good as the content will be dynamic in the future and I need to be able to select the last object in the array

Comment: @MarkHughes88 ok, I think I understand the problem. The indexable dynamic object is most likely not an array, its a `IList` of some sort. Try `Count` instead of `Length`, see if it works.

Comment: you are infact correct. I have posted the solution in OP

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to use Linq in your C# code I see there, it's got a "Last()" extension method you could use.

Like this:

```
        @using System.Linq
        @{var page = Umbraco.Content(1127).Children.Last()}
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. Im unfamiliar with Linq and Im not sure if this project uses it

Comment: That's a shame :( unfortunately I can't help further, I've zero experience with Umbraco :(

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco has a bunch of "isHelpers" including IsLast().  Here is an exanple using isLast.

```
foreach(var page in Umbraco.Content(1127).Children)
{
    if(page.IsLast())
    {
        <h5><a href='@page.Url'>@page.NewsTitle</a></h5>
        <p>@page.NewsIntro</p>
        <p class='read-more'><a href='@page.Url'>Read more...</a></p>
    }
}
```

Here are some of the other isHelpers that Umbraco exposes.

> IsHelper Methods .IsFirst([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse])
>   Test if current node is the first item in the collection
>
> .IsNotFirst([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if
>   current node is not first item in the collection
>
> .IsLast([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if current
>   node is the last item in the collection
>
> .IsNotLast([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if current
>   node is not the last item in the collection
>
> .IsPosition(int index[,string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test
>   if current node is at the specified index in the collection
>
> .IsNotPosition(int index[,string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse])
>   Test if current node is not at the specified index in the collection
>
> .IsModZero([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if current
>   node position evenly dividable (modulus) by a given number
>
> .IsNotModZero([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if
>   current node position is not evenly dividable (modulus) by a given
>   number
>
> .IsEven([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if current
>   node position is even
>
> .IsOdd([string valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Test if current
>   node position is odd
>
> .IsEqual(IPublishedContent otherNode[,string valueIfTrue][,string
>   valueIfFalse]) Tests if the current node in your iteration is
>   equivalent (by Id) to another node
>
> .IsDescendant(IPublishedContent otherNode[,string valueIfTrue][,string
>   valueIfFalse]) Tests if the current node in your iteration is a
>   descendant of another node
>
> .IsDescendantOrSelf(IPublishedContent otherNode[,string
>   valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Tests if the current node in your
>   iteration is a descendant of another node or is the node
>
> .IsAncestor(IPublishedContent otherNode[,string valueIfTrue][,string
>   valueIfFalse]) Tests if the current node in your iteration is an
>   ancestor of another node
>
> .IsAncestorOrSelf(IPublishedContent otherNode[,string
>   valueIfTrue][,string valueIfFalse]) Tests if the current node in your
>   iteration is an ancestor of another node or is the node